# How can I reduce a list by or-ing all its elements together?

Tags: c#, linq

If I'm not mistaken, Linq's `.Aggregate` works like `reduce()` in other languages, doesn't it?

Anyway, I'm trying this:

```
var tags = new[] { "a", "b", "c", ... };
tag.Rule = tags.Aggregate((x, y) => ToTerm(x) | y);
```

But it won't compile because the return type of my lambda has to be a string. So how can I get this to work?

I know it looks funny, because of the types (this is going into an Irony grammar), but all you really need to know that `ToTerm()` returns a `KeyTerm`, and `KeyTerms` can be or'd together to make a `BnfExpression`, which is what tag.Rule is expecting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling the `Aggregate<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TSource, TSource>)` overload, which uses the first value in the sequence as the initial accumulator value.

If you want the accumulator to have a different type from the elements in the sequence, you'll need to specify the initial accumulator value yourself:

```
tag.Rule = tags.Aggregate(BnfExpression.Empty, (x, y) => ToTerm(x) | y);
```

Comment: Close, except now `x` is no longer a string, it's a `BnfExpression` too... which is actually nice, because then we can drop `ToTerm()` as well.

Comment: @Mark: you have the arguments of the lambda reversed.  The first parameter `x` is the value of the seed from the previous iteration.  The second parameter `y` is the current item.

Comment: @Jeff M: That's exactly what I said, isn't it? The seed *is* a `BnfExpression`. `y`, the current item, is a `string`.

Comment: @Mark: As I see it, `ToTerm` is defined as `KeyTerm ToTerm(string)`.  `x` is the seed (of type `BnfExpression` or `KeyTerm`, whichever).  It is not the `string` item in the collection you are reducing.  This is one of the main reasons you should always name your variables correctly.  If named better, you can clearly see why this is wrong: `Aggregate(..., (seed, item) => ToTerm(seed) | item)`

Comment: @Jeff: Yeah.... that is wrong, and that's what Anon wrote... I was commenting how we should drop `ToTerm` if you're using a seed exactly for that reason.

Comment: @Mark: To be fair, it was as you had written in the question and was overlooked unfortunately.  I'd say the naming of the variables was a major contributing factor.  But the idea he was trying to get across was right.

Comment: @Jeff: Yeah... point taken. Was just confused why you said I had it reversed. Will mark this as Accepted, but... it won't work for me since there is no "empty" BnfExpression.

Answer (score 2):

Anon's solution won't work if there's no concept of an empty/identity value.

In my case, there isn't. At least not that I've found.

Thus, I've written this extra overload:

```
public static TRet Aggregate<TRet, TVal>(this IEnumerable<TVal> e, Func<TVal, TRet> seed, Func<TRet, TVal, TRet> func)
{
    return e.Skip(1).Aggregate(seed(e.First()), func);
}
```

Which allows you to process the first element separately. You can call it like this:

```
tagName.Rule = tags.Aggregate(first => (BnfExpression)ToTerm(first), (seed, item) => seed | item);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it makes more sense visually, you can also pre-convert with `.Select`:

```
tag.Rule = tags
    // turn the list into our expected result type
    .Select(item => ToTerm(item))
    // now reduce
    .Aggregate( (seed,item) => seed | item );
```

Which is pretty much the same thing as @Anon's answer using an explicit seed value:

```
var initialSeed = default(TagRule); // or whatever it should be so logic works
tag.Rule = tags.Aggregate( initialSeed, (seed, item) => seed | ToTerm(item) );
```

Comment: That looks like a nice clean solution too. Thanks.